# Find if there are 4 collinear points in a set of points

Tags: math, geometry, 2d

This is a programming contest question. I am only looking for advice as this is just for practice and not for the purpose of cheating etc.

The problem is that I have a set of thousands of points , which have a x and y coordinate (between 10^-10 to 10^10) . I have to find that if there exists any 4 points which are collinear i.e. lie on a straight line.

So far, what I have thought of is the following :

each pair of point, store the y2-y1/x2-x1 in a map with slope as the key and the list of the points as value. 
After storing, look if the same value already exists in the  map and whether the pair of points are different from what you are processing at the moment. If they are different, then you have the set of 4 points that are collinear.

However, the space and time complexity for this problem is O(N^2). Also, this involves a lot of decimal and division operations which decrease the accuracy.

Could anyone suggest a more elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: I am surprised on the down-votes, though yes, the tags of java/c++ seem unnecessary. Otherwise, it is a programming question and the OP has shown effort in solving it.

Comment: @OP your approach as such shall consider even two sets of parallel points as collinear.

Comment: You probably need to keep adding to the list of point pairs in the map till the entry contains three pairs whose union comes to 4 points.

Comment: Division might get tricky if `x1 == x2`.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal What if the value in the key value set was a object which also stored the y intercept , and only on matching the slope and y-intercept will we see if all 4 points are distinct?

Comment: @JoeZ Yes I understand, for that case we might denote the slope as infinite by using a special sentinel value. However, the whole reason I posted this question here was to look for a more elegant solution which could avoid division altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

Basically, for each point (*x*, *y*), you consider every possible line that goes through this point.

Every line can be described by two parameters:

- one choice of parameters is *m* (slope of the line) and *b* (intersection with the y-axis): *y* = *mx* + *b*;
- another choice is ρ (the signed distance of the line from the origin) and θ (the angle of the line): ρ = *x* cos θ + *y* sin θ.

I will be using ρ and θ in the following.

By rounding ρ and θ to a given precision, you can ensure there are a finite number of possible lines through each point. If you measure ρ in steps of 10<sup>8</sup>, there are only 282 possible values for ρ (since the maximum *x* and *y* coordinate is 10<sup>10</sup>). If you measure θ in whole degrees, there are only 180 possible values for θ.

So you can represent every possible line in a 2-dimensional array indexed by (ρ, θ). This is called an *accumulator array*. Let's store the number of points that belong to a given line inside that array:

```
int[,] accumulator = new int[numRho, numTheta]
for each point (x,y):
    for θ from 0° to 179°:
        ρ = x cos θ + y sin θ
        ρ = ρ / 10^8
        accumulator[ρ, θ] ++
```

Now we just need to check the buckets where the accumulator has value of four or more, would  means there are potentially four or more points on one of the lines that falls into that bucket. Of course, since we rounded ρ and θ, we need to check whether those points really lie on the same line (here we could use the naïve O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, or if the number of points found is large, we could repeat this algorithm with a finer subdivision of ρ and θ).

```
for each possible ρ
    for each possible θ
        if accumulator[ρ, θ] >= 4
             find all points in that bucket that are close to the line (ρ, θ)
             check those points for collinearity
```

If we have chosen the resolution of ρ and θ large enough that most buckets contain fewer that four points then we should have an amortized complexity of:

- time: O((number of points + number of values of ρ) × number of values of θ)
- space: O(number of values of ρ × number of values of θ)

Otherwise we need a bigger accumulator array. Still, I think this should be much faster than testing every pair of points.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by find all point that are close to the line. How can we do this?

Comment: so basically , loop through all points and check if they satisfy the equation rho = x cos theta + y sin theta ?

Comment: Also, since the minimum x and y coordinate is 10^-10, wouldn't that mean everything less than 10^8 is considered the same?

Comment: Sorry, my previous somehow comment got cut of. I meant looping through the points and checking if they satisfy the equation, as you correctly deduced. Regarding your next question, yes, I sorta assumed that the points are evenly distributed across the whole range. If the points are not evenly distributed, then rounding to 10^8 probably will not work, and you need some other way to discretize rho such as taking the logarithm before rounding. It is probably best if you adapt this parameter to the actual spread of your points before each run.

Comment: Surely the time complexity is at least O(number of points × number of values of θ) since you consider each value of θ for each point?

Answer (score 0):

For each point Pi have a set of vectors V representing the connections from Pi to each other point Qj where i < j:
If three collinear vectors exist in the set V the points are collinear. (The collinear test is a simple vector_product).

Worst case run time complexity: O(n(n+1)(n+2)/6) == O(n^3)
Space complexity: O(1)

```
// Having a class Point, Vector and a function vector_product

typedef std::vector<Point> Points;
bool find_four_collinear_points(const Points& points) {
    for(unsigned i0 = 0; i0 < points.size(); ++i0) {
        const Point& p0 = points[i0];
        for(unsigned i1 = i0 + 1; i1 < points.size(); ++i1) {
            const Point& p1 = points[i1];
            if(p0 == p1) continue;
            unsigned collinear = 0;
            for(unsigned i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < points.size(); ++i2) {
                const Point& p2 = points[i2];
                if(p0 == p2) continue;
                if(p1 == p2) continue;
                if(vector_product(Vector(p0, p1), Vector(p1, p2)) == 0) {
                    if(++collinear == 3)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution I found to this problem that runs in O(n^2) and is probably the easiest simplest solution. You can probably make it more efficient but I think most iterative solutions will be of this form. (It's in python)

```
def slope(p1,p2):
    if int(p2[0]-p1[0]) is 0:
        return False
    m = (p2[1]-p1[1])/(p2[0]-p1[0])
    return m

def fourOnALine(listoftuples):
    n = len(listoftuples)
    for i in range(n):
        slope_dict = {}
        count = 0
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            m = slope(listoftuples[i], listoftuples[j])
            if m in slope_dict:
                 slope_dict[m]+= 1
            else:
                slope_dict[m] = 1
        for key in slope_dict:
            if slope_dict[key] == 3:
                return True
    return False

print fourOnALine([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(8,8)])#true
print fourOnALine([(5.0,1.0),(5.0,8.0),(3.0,4.0),(7.0,12.0),(-3.0,6.0),(1.0,0.0)])#true
print fourOnALine([(3,9),(-4,9),(0,2),(1,-3),(5,4)])#false
print fourOnALine([(-1000.0,1000.0),(-2000.0,1000.0),(-3000.0,999.0),(-4000.0,1000.0)])#false
```

Comment: This does not take into account the test cases where there are parallel lines, parallel lines have the same slope but points on two parallel lines are not collinear with respect to each other. So I think you need something more than just slope in order to determine collinearity

Comment: It does take into account parallel lines. That is why slope_dict is reset to {} for every iteration inside the first for loop, otherwise you would be correct.

Comment: Essentially the logic is, for every point, find the slope between that point and every other point. If you have encountered 3 slopes of the same value (just for that point) then those 4 points must be collinear.